# Linear Regression not optimizing for non linear data

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am new to ML and am trying my hands on Linear regression. I am using [this](https://www.openml.org/d/40601) dataset. The data and my "optimized" model look like this:

[image]

I am modifying the data like this:

```
X = np.vstack((np.ones((X.size)),X,X**2))
Y = np.log10 (Y)
#have tried roots of Y and 3 degree feature as well
```

Intial cost: 0.8086672720475084

Optimized cost: 0.7282965408177141

I am unable to optimize further no matter the no. of runs.
Increasing learning rate causes increase in cost.

My rest algorithm is fine as I am able to optimize for a simpler dataset. Shown Below:

[image]

Sorry, If this is something basic but I can't seem to find a way to optimize my model for original data.

EDIT:

Pls have look at my code, I don't why its not working

```
def GradientDescent(X,Y,theta,alpha):
m = X.shape[1]
h = Predict(X,theta)
gradient = np.dot(X,(h - Y))
gradient.shape = (gradient.size,1)
gradient = gradient/m
theta = theta - alpha*gradient
cost = CostFunction(X,Y,theta)
return theta,cost

def CostFunction(X,Y,theta):
m = X.shape[1]
h = Predict(X,theta)
cost = h - Y
cost = np.sum(np.square(cost))/(2*m)
return cost

def Predict(X,theta):
h = np.transpose(X).dot(theta)
return h

x is 2,333
y is 333,1
```

I tried debugging it again but I can't find it. Pls help me.

Comment: Using the log10 of the price shown in the data file, I fit the data as "Price = 3.7454287445794540E+02 + (-1.8720506619195038E-01 * Year)" and it fit OK. Notice that my equation uses an offset in addition to requiring the log10 of the data file's raw price values.

Comment: @JamesPhillips can you have look at my code. I see that we are the same modification on dataset yet I am not getting the optimized result.

Comment: I do not see a calculation of gradients for the parameters.

Comment: @JamesPhillips I am using that gradient descent function to optimise the parameters, in a for loop of 1000 runs, later.Do you want me to show that as well?